# Mysterious crashes in Swift 1.2 - in Release builds only

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift

After updating to Xcode 6.3 (beta 1) and Swift 1.2, all my apps are mysteriously crashing *in Release builds only*. They work fine, after updating my code for Swift 1.2, in Debug builds. The debugger gives no sense of *where* the crashes are occurring, and it isn't clear why. Some of the crashes are

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff0c3824800: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Others are "unrecognized selector", but they make no sense; the objects to which the selectors are being sent are not even objects I'm aware of using. It appears that something has gone wrong with memory management, so that one object is being substituted for another.

What on earth could be causing this? With nothing useful in the call stack (so that I don't even know where in my code the crash occurs) and no variables showing up in the variables pane of the debugger when I step through my code (so that I can't even look at the values of things), how could I even begin to track it down?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amazingly, I *did* track this down, mostly by deleting code in large swatches until I was down to just this (it's a view controller):

```
class LessonListController: UIViewController {
    var terms : [Term]
    // var terms : NSArray
    init(terms data:NSArray) {
        let arr = data.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "lessonSection", ascending: true)])
        self.terms = arr as! [Term]
        // self.terms = arr
        super.init(nibName:"LessonList", bundle:nil)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    @IBAction func doDismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If (in a Release build) we present this view controller and then dismiss it, we crash on dismiss - in dealloc, which proves my theory that it's a problem with memory management.

Having isolated the code, I was able to try various alternatives. It is clear that the problem is the property `var terms : [Term]` (because the only thing Swift is doing under the hood in `dealloc` is releasing this array). The value of this property, as you can see in my `init`, is an NSArray that has come from Cocoa (thru `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`) and has been cast to a Swift array. By trial and error, I discovered:

- If we change the implementation so that the property is an NSArray (see the commented-out alternative lines), we don't crash.
- Or, if we don't sort (so that this NSArray doesn't come from Cocoa), we don't crash.
- Or (wait for it), if we replace `self.terms = arr as! [Term]` with `self.terms = arr as NSArray as! [Term]`, we don't crash!

But that third alternative *is a workaround*. I went through all my code in all my apps looking for `as! [SomeType]` casts and replaced them all with `as NSArray as [SomeType]`, and *all my crashes went away!!*

My theory is that something is going wrong with Swift's memory management in the optimized Release build just in the very specific situation where an NSArray arrives from Cocoa and is bridged for us to an `[AnyObject]` before our code can get hold of it. Such an NSArray is not crossing the bridge properly. But by casting to NSArray and then back to down to the specific `[SomeType]` Swift array, the problem is solved.

Naturally, I assume that when Apple figures this out, they'll fix it and then we can stop using this workaround. But until then, my apps are running in a Release build once again.

Comment: And my bug report number is 19835848. So if you see this in your own apps and you want to report it, you can reference my report if you like.

Comment: this also happens to me, with a String. i did not figure out a workaround yet

Comment: @alexdd55 I've heard about the String version of the problem but I haven't seen it. I'd like to. Have you got a reproducible case? (And have you filed a bug report with Apple?)

Comment: My Xcode 6.3 beta Swift 1.2 release builds were also crashing on launch. Under Build Settings I searched for "Optimization Level" and set both to "None". That stopped the crashing.

Comment: @matt could you help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867698/app-with-objective-c-and-swift-code-crash-at-launch-in-release-mode-debug-mode/30868109?noredirect=1#comment49778124_30868109? though I have no idea how to start it... no log to find

Comment: I haven't experienced crashes, but I also see the memory is being overwritten in Release builds in Swift 1.2, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533909/accessor-gives-the-wrong-value-in-swift-1-2-release-build-only

Comment: @endavid But the problem is gone in Swift 2.0, yes?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not :( The problem persists in Swift 2.0.