# Accessor gives the wrong value in Swift 1.2/2.0 Release build only

Tags: swift

I found a very strange bug in my code that only happens in Release builds. It looks like a Swift bug to me, but let me know what you think.

```
import Foundation

enum Level : Int {
    case
    Bad     = 0,
    Normal  = 1,
    Good    = 2,
    Superb  = 3
}

struct Attribute : Printable {
    var x : Level = .Normal
    var y : Level = .Normal
    var z : Level = .Normal
    var w : Level = .Normal

    var description : String {
        return "(\(x.rawValue), \(y.rawValue), \(z.rawValue), \(w.rawValue))"
    }

    func toString() -> String {
        return description
    }
}


var AccessorBugTestSingleton : AccessorBugTest!

class AccessorBugTest {

    let index       : Int
    var attributes  : [Attribute] = []
    var todaysAttributes : Attribute {
        get {
            let r = attributes[index]
            println("today: \(r)")
            return r
        }
    }
    var initialText : String = ""
    // selection for key
    var states  : [String:Int] = ["x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0, "w": 0]
    var descriptions  : [String:Int] = ["a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0]


    init() {
        index = 10
        for i in 1...31 {
            var att = Attribute(x: .Superb, y: .Superb, z: .Superb, w: .Superb)
            attributes.append(att)
        }

        let attribs = todaysAttributes
        initialText = "\(attribs)"
        println("init: \(attribs), \(self.attributes[index])")
    }

}
```

When AccessorBugTest is instantiated, it should print

```
init: (3, 3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3, 3)
```

but in Release builds it prints,

```
init: (3, 0, 0, 0), (3, 3, 3, 3)
```

If I remove the unused properties `states` and `descriptions`, then the problem is fixed, no idea why. Also, if I make `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` Ints instead of enums, then it works properly again.

Any idea of what's going on?

I've uploaded the program to: https://github.com/endavid/AccessorBugTest
It contains a test case that will fail if you run it in Release configuration (go to Program -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, and change Test to Release instead of Debug).

I've also downloaded Xcode 7.1 beta, tried in Swift 2.0, and the problem still exists :(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to push the changes. It was just the code I've put in this ticket. It's straight-forward to convert it to Swift 2.0 if you load the code in Xcode 7.1, but I've created a branch in github with the Swift 2.0 code, https://github.com/endavid/AccessorBugTest/tree/swift2

Comment: I thought if I run under Xcode 7.1 and iPhone6 simulator iOS9, the code would run using Swift 2.0. Isn't that the case? I merged your pull request and it's still failing. Do I need to select "Swift 2" somewhere in Xcode? I can't get Xcode 7 GM atm, but anyway, I'm more worried about Swift 1.2 since I have to fix the app that I already released for iOS8. I can fix that particular case, but I need to know if there's a bug in Swift 1.2, exactly what makes it fail to avoid that everywhere in the code and submit a fix of my app in Swift 1.2.

Comment: Okay, I was able to reproduce the bug at last. And I have a workaround that doesn't require you to change your architecture - not very much, anyway. :)

Comment: Perhaps this is what is fixed in Xcode 7.1 beta 2: "A bug was fixed where printing certain enums would report all non-payload cases as the first non-payload
case. (22192074)"

Comment: I verified in the latest stable Xcode 7.1 with Swift 2.1 that the bug has been fixed :) I've updated the README file in the github repository. I'll leave the code there for reference.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've found a bug. A really interesting bug.

And I have a workaround for you: make Attribute a class instead of a struct. It will still be a value class, so the overhead will be low. You will have to give it an initializer that does what the struct memberwise initializer does. You'll find that the whole problem goes away when you do this.

**EDIT:** I thought of an even better workaround: Instead of making Attribute a class, make Level an `@objc` enum.

**EDIT:** The OP reports that this bug is fixed in Swift 2.1.

Comment: So you can see from this that I am hypothesizing that the bug has to do with how a struct of enums is copied. But I have not worked very hard on this hypothesis; I just tried stuff until I found a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! That workaround is good in Swift 1.2 as well :) I changed it to class and added a constructor, init(x: Level, y: Level, z: Level, w: Level) and now it works. I submitted a bug report to Apple a couple of days ago, #22673382, but I didn't get any reply yet. I hope we can get some good explanation on the issue...

Comment: I'm an idiot. Or at least I was, until just now, when I thought of an even better workaround. The theory here is that the root of the problem is the nature of enum storage; marking the enum as `@objc` changes that storage to be more like simple Int storage, which, as you have already said, works fine. (I'm guessing that a non-`@objc` enum uses something more like bitfields; that's what I would do if I were designing the language, anyway.)

Comment: Oh, yes, that's the easiest fix :) And to be safe, I think I'll replace all the enums in my app with @objc enums for the current release. Thanks!

Comment: I knew you'd like it. :) Note that only Int-raw-value enums can be @objc enums.