# Optimization level affects comparing enums

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

For some reasons for Optimization Level Fast my comparing method returns extra 3 elements. Is it a problem with my code or it's a bug in swift 2.0? Problem occurs on XCode 7.0 and XCode 7.1 (2 different Mac's).

```
func ==(lhs: ViewController.ItemType, rhs: ViewController.ItemType) -> Bool {
    // For some reasons for different types e.g. .CType and .AType it returns true
    switch(lhs, rhs) {
    case (.AType, .AType):
        return true
    case (let .BType(type1), let .BType(type2)):
        return type1 == type2
    case (.CType,.CType):
        return true
    case (.DType, .DType):
        return true
    case (.EType,.EType):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    enum ItemType {
        case AType
        case BType(Int)
        case CType
        case DType
        case EType
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let array:[ItemType] = [.AType, .BType(10), .CType, .DType, .EType]
        let array2 = array.filter { (itemType:ItemType) -> Bool in
            return itemType == .CType
        }

        // Prints 1 on [-ONone] optimization and 4 for [-OFast] optimization.
        print("Items \(array2.count):\n\(array2)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you update to Xcode 7.1?

Comment: It was tested on different XCode versions with the same result.

Comment: I asked because it looks related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533909/accessor-gives-the-wrong-value-in-swift-1-2-2-0-release-build-only It may well be that there's a part of this bug that still isn't fixed. Enums are stored in a highly optimized way and this may have side effects.

Comment: I did some experiments and I think it's connected to opimization as you said e.g. If I will add `print("")` before `return true/false` in overriden operator  code works correctly.

Comment: It's an excellent bug; please report it to Apple.

Comment: the same for Xcode 7.2 beta (7C46l), the possible workaround is
a) use more than one case with associated value of 'numeric' type or
b) use IntegerType or FloatingPointType as associated value

Comment: The simplest way to avoid the problem is to add local variable http://pastie.org/10528688

Comment: Did you file a radar?

Comment: Only I reported bug only on Apple system at 30 Oct and still my ticket has no value.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around a bit with this. Here's a minimal example:

```
struct Foo {
    enum Enum {
        case A
        case B
        case C(Int)
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Foo.Enum, rhs: Foo.Enum) -> Bool {
    print("comparing \(lhs) == \(rhs) -> ", terminator: "")

    switch(lhs, rhs) {
    case (.A, .A):
        return true
    case (.B,.B):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func test() {
    print(  Foo.Enum.A          == .B)
    print([ Foo.Enum.A ][0]     == .B)
    print([ Foo.Enum.A ].first! == .B)
    for itemType in [ Foo.Enum.A ] { print(itemType == .B) }
}

test()
```

In -Onone builds this prints the expected four times true. In optimized builds it prints...

```
comparing A == B -> false
comparing A == B -> false
comparing A == B -> true
comparing A == B -> true
```

The bug disappears when:

- The test is performed in the outer file scope (not in a function)
- A normal function is used instead of operator `==`
- The enum is not nested in another type
- The `case C` or the associated type is removed
- `print` statements are inserted into the `switch` cases

I've been testing with Xcode 7.1. This bug should definitely been filed at bugreport.apple.com